# Characterization of homogeneous polynomials over R

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm trying to prove the following:

Let $P(x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}[x_1, \dots, x_n]$, and suppose that

$P(a_1, \dots, a_n) = 0 \implies P(ta_1, \dots, ta_n) = 0 \text{ } \text{ } \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$

Then $P(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ is homogeneous.

Thanks!

Comment: That sounds false. Consider $\sum_i x_i^2+1$.

Comment: @jgon I think you're right.  Hmmm...  Time to ponder this more deeply.

Answer (score 1):

You can write $f$ as the sum of homogeneous polynomials, say
$$f=f_d+f_{d-1}+\cdots+f_0$$
where $\deg f_m=m$, and $d=\deg f$. Now, denote $a=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$, if $f(a)=0$, implies $f(ta)=0$, this is:
$$f(ta)=t^df_d(a)+t^{d-1}f_{d-1}(a)+\cdots+tf_1(a)+f_0(a)=0$$
as this is zero for all $t$, then $f_n(a)=0$ for all $n$. 
This give us an idea for a counter example: For instance $g(x,y)=x^2+y^4$, if $g(a,b)=0$, then $a=b=0$ (we are on the reals) we have that $g(ta,tb)=t^2a^2+t^4b^4=0$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

So it is FALSE.

Comment: You are RIGHT.  ;)

Or we could take jgon's example of a polynomial which vacuously satisfies the condition but isn't homogeneous.