# Characterization of homogeneous polynomials over algebraically closed fields

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

Suppose $K$ is an algebraically closed field and $f\in K[\bar{x}]$ has the following property for all $\bar{a}\in K^n$:
$$f(\bar{a})=0 \implies f(t\bar{a})=0\qquad\text{for all }t\in K$$
(Here $\bar{x}$ is short for $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, likewise $\bar{a}$.) So whenever $f$ is zero at a point, it is zero on the line through the origin and that point.

Then I claim $f$ is homogeneous. (This is false if we drop the algebraic closure assumption, as in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3261668/characterization-of-homogeneous-polynomials-over-r).)

I haven't found this stated in any textbooks so far, even as an exercise. I'd appreciate any references, or indications of flaws in my reasoning (below).

Consider the principle ideal $(f)$. $\mathbf{V}((f))$ consists of lines through the origin in $K^n$, by assumption. If $f$ vanishes on such a line passing through $\bar{a}$ ($\neq \bar{0}$), then so do all its homogeneous parts, by the usual argument: $f(t\bar{a})$ is a polynomial in $t$ with infinitely many roots. So if $h$ is a homogeneous part, then (by the Nullstellensatz) $h^k$ belongs to $(f)$ for some $k$. In other words, $f|h^k$. But $h^k$ is homogeneous, and any factor of a homogeneous polynomial is homogeneous.

Comment: Do you mean that there is a point $\bar{a}$ for which $f(t\bar{a}) = 0$ for all $t \in K$, or that this holds whenever $f$ vanishes at $\bar{a}$?

Comment: @HuguesBellemare Thanks. The second. I've edited the question to make this clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct. Likewise, I've never seen this result explicitly stated somewhere, but you can find the argument hidden in some proofs of the projective strong Nullstellensatz. For example, look at the proof of Theorem $9$, $\S 3$, Chapter $8$ in the book *Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms* by Cox, Little and O'Shea. Using their notation, consider the ideal $I = (f)$, the affine cone $C_V = \mathbf{V}(I)$ and the associated projective variety $V = \mathbf{V}(h_i)$, where the $h_i$'s are the homogeneous parts of $f$. The proof then proceeds to show that $\sqrt{I} = \mathbf{I}(V)$, which partially recovers your argument.